# Place a label to the left of a tikz/pgf plot

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a plot which I create by `\addplot` and I would like to set a label to the left of the function graph *at a specific x position of the function*. How is that possible? I've tried `note[pos = ...]`, but it simply places the node above the `x`-axis and not above the function graph (which is what I want). Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning}

\begin{document}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal_distribution}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\section{}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[domain=-6:6, axis lines*=left, xlabel=$x$, samples=1000, scale only axis, width = \textwidth]
            \addplot [very thick, blue!50!black] {normal_distribution} node[pos = 0.5, above]{$f(x)$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You probably want `extra x tick`. See [the PGFPlots manual](https://tikz.dev/pgfplots/reference-tickoptions).

Comment: Your example doesn't work here, but if I replace the function with `rnd`, I do get the f(x)-label just above the function graph.

Comment: Looking again, you've defined the `normal_distribution` function to take two arguments, but you've passed none. Try e.g. `\addplot  {normal_distribution(0,2)} node[above]{foo};`, and if that doesn't get you what you need, please edit the question to clarify :)

Answer (score 0):

maybe like this ?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, calc, positioning, intersections}

\pgfmathdeclarefunction{normal_distribution}{2}{%
    \pgfmathparse{1/(#2*sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-((x-#1)^2)/(2*#2^2))}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            domain=-6:6, 
            axis lines*=left, 
            xlabel=$x$, 
            samples=100,
            scale only axis, 
            width=\textwidth,
            no markers
        ]
            \addplot [very thick, blue!50!black, name path=plot] {normal_distribution(0,1)};

            % x where you want the label
            \pgfmathsetmacro\labelx{-2}

            % invisible line at this coordinate
            \path[name path=vertical line] (axis cs:\labelx,-10) -- (axis cs:\labelx,10);

            % intersection to place the node
            \draw [
                name intersections={of=vertical line and plot, by=point},
                draw=none
            ] (point) node [left] {$f(x)$};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]